# Is $O(n \cdot n!) = O(n!)$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, factorial

I was reading about Bogo Sort average time complexity, which is $O(n \cdot n!)$.
In this case, would it be right to just ignore the first factor n, following the rule

$$O(\log n) < O(n) < O(n \log n) < O(n^2) < O(n!) < O(n^n)?$$

Is $O(n!)$ the same as $O(n \cdot n!)$?
Or is $O(n \cdot n!) > O(n!)$?

Comment: Consider $\dfrac{ n\times n!}{ n!}$.  Is this bounded above?

Comment: Take $(n+1)!$. $ $ $ $

Comment: @Exodd That would tell you $ O(n \times n!)$ is  $O((n+1)!)$ but not whether it is  $O( n!)$

Comment: @Henry $(n+1)!$ is $O(n\cdot n!)$ but it is not $O(n!)$ so they are not the same

Comment: Never heard about "Bogo sort"... Can you give some reference ?

Comment: It's a probabilistic sorting algorithm that shuffles the data structure and checks if it is sorted. If not, repeats the process.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort
Also called "Stupid Sort"

Comment: @Daniel Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $n!=O(n\cdot n!)$ is true but $n\cdot n!=O(n!)$ is false, so they do not have the same time complexity. To show this clearly, you may use the limit definition, $n!=O(n\cdot n!)$ is equivalent to the statement

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{n!}{n\cdot n!}\right| =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} < \infty,$$
which is true. Can you disprove $n\cdot n!=O(n!)$ by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I can! Thanks, I think I understand now!