# $T(n) = nT(n-1) + n^2$ analysis

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I did a good amount of research on the above recurrence relation. It is the recurrence relation for N-Queens problem using backtracking. In this link here is a proof of how it reduces to $O(n^2)\times O((n-2)! + n!)$. However, in the end it finally reduces to $O(n!)$.

https://www.codesdope.com/course/algorithms-backtracking/

Is there not any difference between $O(n^2 \cdot (n-2)!)$ (which is quite similar to $O(n^2 \cdot n!))$ and $O(n!)$?

I used graphing calculator to draw graph of both the functions and observed that they have similar rate of growth. However, I found one answer here [Is $O(n \cdot n!) = O(n!)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4080304/is-on-cdot-n-on) which made me think that the above conversion is wrong.

After looking at many articles I have got confused. I will be thankful if someone can explain me where I might be going wrong.

I apologize for improper formatting. I am not used to typing mathematical expression. I am a stack overflow user and have no experience of math stackexchange. If anyone can edit the formatting used in my question, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: $(n-2)!$ misses to factors from $n!$. The numbers you compare are $n\cdot n\cdot (n-2)!$, the other one is $n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)!$. So both of them are $(n-2)!$ times a degree $2$ polynomial in $n$. It is clear that $n!\leq n^2\cdot (n-2)!$. However we also have $n^2\cdot (n-2)!\leq 2\cdot n!$ (as $n-1\leq 2n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(n) = O (n^2) \cdot O((n-2)!) +O(n!)$ means there exists a positive number $k$ and a positive integer $N_0$ such that $T(n) \le k \cdot (n^2 (n-2)! + n!)$ or all $n >N_0$

Note that $n^2(n-2)! + n! = n^2(n-2)! + (n^2-n)(n-2)! = (2n^2-n)(n-2)! <3(n^2-n)(n-2)!= 3n!$ for $n >2$.

So,
$$T(n) \le k \cdot (n^2 (n-2)! + n!) <3k\cdot n! $$
for all $n > N_0 + 2$.
That is, $T(n) = O(n!)$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got confused and thought $n^2(n-2)!$ and $n^2n!$ mean the same. I do understand now that they are different and how the first one reduces to $O(n!)$ and the second one does not. Thank you for your time.